# Class initialiser error - C++

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I'm trying to create a class of complex numbers in C++, but I'm getting a strange error for the initialiser of the class here is a screenshot of the error :

[image]

And here is my code :

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cmath"
#include "Complexx.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

complex c(1,1);
std::cout << c.realPart << "+" <<c.imaginaryPart << "i";
return 0;
}
```

Complexx.h :

```
#ifndef Functions_Complexx_h
#define Functions_Complexx_h
#include "cmath"
using namespace std;

class complex {

public:
double imaginaryPart;
double realPart;
complex(double realPart, double imaginaryPart);
double modulus();
};
#endif
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are the definitions?

Comment: Where is your implementation? Are you building it and linking it?

Comment: You didn't define the constructor.

Comment: Actually - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided a definition for the `complex(double, double)` constructor, although a declaration is provided. This is what the linker complains about.

Add this to a `.cpp` file in your project which `#include`s your header file `complexx.h` (possibly `complexx.cpp`):

```
complex::complex(double realPart, double imaginaryPart)
    :
    realPart(realPart),
    imaginaryPart(imaginaryPart)
{ }
```

It is possible that the same problem exists for `double modulus()`, for which no linker error is issued because you are not invoking it (yet).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here.

```
complex(double realPart, double imaginaryPart);
```

You've *declared* a constructor, but you haven't *defined* it.  That's why the linker is complaining about `undefined symbol complex::complex(double, double)`

This is probably the *definition* you want - to store those two parameters in the object.

```
complex(double realPart, double imaginaryPart)
  : realPart(realPart)
  , imaginaryPart(imaginaryPart)
{ }
```

It doesn't matter what those parameters are named.  C++ will not infer that because they have the same names as your member variables that they should be copied to the object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't linked the definition of the `complex(double, double)` constructor.
This may be caused by the fact that you forgot to link `Complexx.cpp` (assuming the name of the cpp file is the same as the header file) or that you totally forgot to define the constructor inside the linked `Complexx.cpp` file.

Just run this g++ commands when compiling main.cpp (assuming you are using gcc):

```
g++ -c Complexx.cpp -o Complexx.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ main.o Complexx.o -o app
```